# CakePHP Save Primary Key of associated table as Foreign Key of another

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

So i'm currently figuring out how to add users. Adding an email record then using the Auto-incremented Emails id to assign to email_id in Users table with that id being a dependent.

[image: users and emails tables]

I'm doing it all from the users controller

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {//specify we are getting PostData
        $data = [
        //'id' => '111',
        'address' => $this->request->data['Emails']['address'],
        'created' => Time::now(),
        'last_modified' => Time::now(),
        'last_contacted' => Time::now() ];  

        $emails = TableRegistry::get('Emails');

        $email = $emails->newEntity($data, [ 'associated' => ['Users']]);   
        $save = $emails->save($email, ['associated' => 'Users']);
        $email_id = $save->id;


        $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $user = $users->newEntity($this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['Emails.id']]);
        $user->dob = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user->dob));
        $user->email['id'] = $email_id;
        $user->is_admin = 'n';
        $user->last_login = Time::now();
        $user->created = Time::now();
        $user->last_modified = Time::now();


        if ($emails->save($email, ['associated' => 'Users'])) {

            if($users->save($user, ['associated' => 'Emails'])) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('User could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }else {             
            $this->Flash->error(__('Email save failure, please try again.'));   
        }

    }
    $emails = $this->Users->Emails->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('user', 'emails'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);

}
```

which takes data in from the form:

`   Form->create(  ) ?>

```
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('Emails.address', ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Email']);
        echo $this->Form->control('Users.password', ['required' => true, 'label' => 'Password']);
        echo $this->Form->label('Gender');
        echo $this->Form->radio('Users.gender',['m'=>'Male', 'f' => 'Female'] , [ 'required' => true]);
        echo $this->Form->control('Users.family_name', [ 'required' => true, 'label' => 'Given Name']);
        echo $this->Form->control('Users.given_name', [ 'required' => true,  'label' => 'Family Name']);
        echo $this->Form->control('Users.dob', [ //birth date between 1900 and current year
          'data-format'=>'d m Y',
          'class' => 'dateinput',
          'required' => true,
          'data-default-date'=> '03-30-1993',
          'maxYear' => date('Y') - 17, 

          ]);
        echo $this->Form->control('Users.phone', [ 'required' => true]);

    ?>

</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class'=>'text-right']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>`
```

SO my problem is that i can create email addresses and make them save - great.

EMails and Users are a hasOne. defined in emails table

```
     `$this->hasOne('Users', [

    'foreignKey' => 'emails_id', 'bindingKey' => 'id', ])
    ->setDependent(true)
    ->setName('Emails');
    `
```

I just cant seem to take the users input and add that into the table. Errors include:

**Cannot marshal data for "Emails" association. It is not associated with "Users"** which happens when i only put the hasone in the UsersTable. Same if I only have it in EmailsTable. [Dp it when the *other* model contains the fk](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasone-associations)

**ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails** which happens when both have hasOne in it and i make the email first. It still says theres no fk relation

Comment: Wich CakePHP version are you using?

Comment: CakePHP version 3.4

Comment: No time for an answer right now... I would suggest that you first read up on how saving/marshalling associations works, what you're doing there isn't necessary, and it's full of snares: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations** | **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data**.

Comment: thanks yeah been reading that for ages. it just doesnt wanna save.